# Unable to Move the List of values from Right Combo bx to Left Combo bx (Multiple List of values)

Tags: javascript

```
function listbox_moveacross(sourceID, destID) {
    var src = document.getElementById(sourceID);
    var dest = document.getElementById(destID);
    var errCount = 0;
    for (var count = 0; count < src.options.length; count++) {
        if (src.options[count].selected == true) {
            var option = src.options[count];
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = option.value;
            newOption.text = option.text;
            newOption.selected = true;
            try {
                dest.add(newOption, null); // Standard
                src.remove(count, null);
            } catch (error) {
                dest.add(newOption); // IE only         
                src.remove(count);
            }
            count--;
            errCount++;
        }
    }
    if (errCount == 0) {
        alert("No Element Selected or you have no element to move");
    }
}
```

Hi Can any body help on JavaScript Given code will be for moving list of values from Right to Left and Left to user can select the multiple values in given list but in my case i am unable to move list of values from Right to Left but it is working fine with Left to Right

Comment: can you please format

Comment: In the least rude way possible, look at that code.  Do you really expect anyone to derive anything meaningful with that formatting?  Also, java is to javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: That wasn't easy to format :)

Comment: @user2579718 Why are you `count--;` in your loop? this will effectively stop the loop from ever moving onto the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>try removing `count--;` from your code I have a feeling this is preventing the loop from moving onto the next iteration if it finds a selected item in the list.</strike>

seems to work fine to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/xBDKg/